# How to close the browser after completing a download?

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How to make browser closed after completing download?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get(any_url)
browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//input[@value="Download"]').click()

# The program start downloading now.

# HERE WHAT IS THE CODE?

browser.quit()
```

I want to close the browser only after completing the download.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to use the below piece of code right before you close the browser.

`time.sleep(5)`# Gives time to complete the task before closing the browser. You 
                 may increase the seconds to 10 or 15,basically the amount of time 
                 required for download otherwise it goes to the next step 
                 immediately.

```
browser.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternative way I did on C#. Maybe you can use the same technique and apply it on python.

```
public static string GetRequest(string url, bool isBinary = false) {
    // binary is the file that will be downloaded
    // Here you perform asynchronous get request and download the binary
    // Python guide for GetRequest -> http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/
}

browser.webdriver.Firefox();
browser.get(any_url);
elem = browser.findElement("locator");
GetRequest(elem.getAttribute('href'), true); // when this method is done, you expect the get request is done
browser.quit();
```

Answer (score 1):

The trick that I used was to open the download manager page and expect by one element that indicate that the download is finished. Follow the Python code used:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

...

# Wait until the download finish. This code just works for one single download at time on Firefox.
# browser.execute_script('window.open();')
# ActionChains(browser).key_down(Keys.COMMAND).send_keys('t').key_up(Keys.COMMAND).perform()
browser.get('about:downloads')
# files = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('download-state')
WebDriverWait(browser, URL_LOAD_TIMEOUT).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'downloadIconShow')))
# 'downloadIconCancel'

browser.close()
broswer.quit()
```

The problem of this approach is that it may be dependent of Firefox version, if Mozilla change that download manager page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pause command:

```
pause ( waitTime )
```

Wait for the specified amount of time (in milliseconds)

http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/1.0/reference.html#pause

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get(any_url)
browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//input[@value="Download"]').click()

# The program start downloading now.

pause (10000) # pause/sleeps for 10 seconds

browser.quit()
```

Comment: I want to close the browser only after completing the download. @Tuga

Comment: is not your code is using the assumption that the file downloading is finished with in 10 seconds? @Tuga

Comment: I am, increase it if you need it.