# How to click on save button in download bar which comes at bottom of the page in IE 10,11 using c#without using 3rd party tools

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

How to click on save button in download bar which comes at bottom of the page in IE 10,11 using c#. It would be great if it is a small piece of code as i am new to programming.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I wanted to try but this occurs for my team mate and i wanted to help. I read about System.Windows.Forms.Sendkeys.Sendwait("{TAB}"); i can send ALT+ S through this but after saving will control pass to web application again. Just need a proven working solution.Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the below link
[download file stored Location and handling Download Popup using selenium webdriver with JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21255338/download-file-stored-location-and-handling-download-popup-using-selenium-webdriv)

or else please try with Autoit tool