# Save dialog not able to Interact - Selenium Webdriver with Java

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, autoit

before, i'm new for this AutoIT, i'm not familiar with this, just google and need to complete my task, if any mistake of my AtotoIt please correct it

scope: 
during the Xml Download from IE(version 9) it will open the "Do you want to open or save dialog" so i want to click the save button to save that xml file in default temp folder
[image]

my autoIT code(reference from http://qtp-help.blogspot.in/2009/07/selenium-handle-dialogs.html#handle_save_dialog)

```
AutoItSetOption("WinTitleMatchMode","2") ; set the select mode to select using substring

if $CmdLine[0] < 2 then
; Arguments are not enough
msgbox(0,"Error","Supply all the arguments, Dialog title,Run/Save/Cancel and Path to     save(optional)")
Exit
EndIf

; wait Until dialog box appears
WinWait($CmdLine[1]) ; match the window with substring
$title = WinGetTitle($CmdLine[1]) ; retrives whole window title
WinActivate($title)

If (StringCompare($CmdLine[2],"Open",0) = 0) Then
WinActivate($title)
ControlClick($title,"","Button1")
EndIf

If (StringCompare($CmdLine[2],"Save",0) = 0) Then
WinWaitActive($title)
ControlClick($title,"","Button2")
; Wait for the new dialogbox to open
EndIf

If (StringCompare($CmdLine[2],"Cancel",0) = 0) Then
WinWaitActive($title)
ControlClick($title,"","Button3")
EndIf
```

My java code

```
WebElement downloadLink = driver.findElement(By
            .xpath("(//img[@alt='Download'])[3]"));
    downloadLink.click();
    Thread.sleep(4000);
    dialog = new String[] {
            "C:\\Users\\Prabakar\\Desktop\\Save_Dialog_IE.exe", "Save" };
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(dialog);
```

Please help to solve

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at other ways to download the file without using AutoIT.

[How to make browser closed after completing download?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21217087/how-to-make-browser-closed-after-completing-download/21241682#21241682)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <_XMLDomWrapper.au3>
#include <File.au3>

Global $oXML = ObjCreate("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
$oXML.Open("GET", "YOUR URL LIKE: http://www.google.com", 0)
$oXML.Send

Global $sFile = _TempFile(@TempDir, '~', '.xml')
FileWrite($sFile, $oXML.responseText)
```

Would this work for you? The XMLDomWrapper.au3 can you get from [HERE](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/19848-xml-dom-wrapper-com/)

[Source](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/98514-parse-xml-file/#entry708997)